# Android opening PUSH GCM notifications crash app when click on notification (Intent Variable can't provide value of "Extras")

Tags: android, database, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

**[Updated 08/01/16]**

I'm developing an application that uses push notifications messages that works very fine when the application is already running. The problem occurs when i click on notification when the application is not running, tracking the error I found the root of the problem: Always when a new message comes, the app shows the message in a listview and makes a backup of message on a database, when i try to save the message on database in this conditions the database insert method return an index value of "-1", this happens because the intent variable after of click on the `notification` comes with extra values that returns null, these null values causes problems.

**[EDIT 1]**

**Messageactivity.java**

```
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private ListView lista;
    public List<Message> listMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    public MessageAdapter adapter;
    private PrefManager pref;
    private List<Recados> recados;
    RecadosDataSource rec;
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    boolean opened=false;


    private class Item {
        final String Titulo, Descricao, data;

        Item(String Titulo, String Descricao,String data) {
            this.Titulo = Titulo;
            this.Descricao = Descricao;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    void databaseManager(boolean Open){
        if(Open & !opened){
            opened=true;
            rec = new RecadosDataSource(this);
            try {
                rec.open();
            }catch (SQLException e)
            {
                Log.e("SQL","Problema abrindo banco de dados");
            }

        }else{
            opened=false;
            rec.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.parse_list);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Recados");
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bgtitle));
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.paradaxv_crop);

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        //setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
       // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        databaseManager(true);
        if(extras!=null)
        {
            rec.updateRecados(intent);
        }

        String email = intent.getStringExtra("email");

        if (email != null) {
            ParseUtils.subscribeWithEmail(pref.getEmail(),"","","","");
        }

        adapter = new MessageAdapter(this);
        pref = new PrefManager(getApplication());

        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        //rec.updateRecados(intent);

        String Titulo = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        String mensagem = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
        String now = df.format(new Date());

        items.add(new Item(Titulo, mensagem, now));

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        databaseManager(true);
    }

    public class MessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MessageAdapter(Context context) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            recados = rec.getAllRecados();

            try{
            for (Recados reca : recados) {

                items.add(new Item(reca.getTitulo(),reca.getDescricao(),reca.getData_recado()));

             }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(context,"DEu Ruim inflando a lista",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            /*Fechando banco de dados*/
            databaseManager(false);

        }




        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return items.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_parse, null);
            }

            TextView txtTitulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.RecadoTitle);
            TextView txtMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
            TextView txtTimestamp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);

          //  Message message = listMessages.get(position);
          //  txtMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
          //  txtTitulo.setText(message.getTitle());
          //  txtTimestamp.setText(message.);

          //  CharSequence ago = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(message.getTimestamp(), System.currentTimeMillis(),
          //          0L, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);

            //txtTimestamp.setText(String.valueOf(ago));


            Item item = (Item) getItem(position);

            txtTitulo.setText(item.Titulo);
            txtMessage.setText(item.Descricao);
            txtTimestamp.setText(item.data);


            return view;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

  /*  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
            pref.logout();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);*/
    //}

    private void inflaLista(){

    }
}
```

**RecadosDataSource.java**

```
public RecadosDataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new BancoDados(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {

    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

}


public Recados updateRecados(Intent intent) {

    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    Cursor cursor;

    Titulo = intent.getStringExtra("title");
    valores.put(BancoDados.COLUNA_TITULO_RECADO, Titulo);
    mensagem = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    valores.put(BancoDados.COLUNA_DESCRICAO_RECADO, mensagem);

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
    String now = df.format(new Date());

    valores.put(BancoDados.COLUNA_DATA_RECADO, now);


    long insertId=database.insert(BancoDados.TABELA_NOME_RECADOS, null, valores);

    cursor= database.query(BancoDados.TABELA_NOME_RECADOS, allColumns,
                            BancoDados.COLUNA_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                            null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    novoRecado = cursorToRecado(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    valores.clear();

    return novoRecado;

}
```

**LOGCAT OUTPUT**

```
01-09 11:55:41.424    3238-3238/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1299) abort at 8 in [INSERT INTO Recados(titulo,descricao,data) VALUES (?,?,?)]: NOT NULL constraint failed: Recados.titulo
01-09 11:55:41.432    3238-3238/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting titulo=null descricao=null data=09/01/16 11:55
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: Recados.titulo (code 1299)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
            at igparadaxv.igbparadaxv.Parse.RecadosDataSource.updateRecados(RecadosDataSource.java:95)
            at igparadaxv.igbparadaxv.Parse.MessageActivity.onCreate(MessageActivity.java:102)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
01-09 11:55:41.438    3238-3238/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: igparadaxv.igbparadaxv, PID: 3238
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{igparadaxv.igbparadaxv/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv.Parse.MessageActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
            at igparadaxv.igbparadaxv.Parse.RecadosDataSource.cursorToRecado(RecadosDataSource.java:152)
            at igparadaxv.igbparadaxv.Parse.RecadosDataSource.updateRecados(RecadosDataSource.java:102)
            at igparadaxv.igbparadaxv.Parse.MessageActivity.onCreate(MessageActivity.java:102)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

**[EDIT 2]**

I find the problem: When i pass the intent variable i can't get the extras values, for this the values to be put in the database are null causing the problem. Why this occurs?

Comment: Post logcat error for more information.

Comment: put your code and log

Comment: @Shane more information add.

Comment: Are added new field in database after creating it?

Comment: @Shane no the database is always the same and contains the same fields.

Comment: Show insert function and first try to rename the database.

Comment: @Shane i fixed the post to show the insert method

Comment: I am sharing code for - how to create database and create table and how to insert and retrive data from DB, cross-check your code and find error- here is link - https://www.dropbox.com/s/r618shv7rvouoo6/SQL.txt?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100146/discussion-between-julianoliveira-and-shane).

Comment: Hi, Did you figure out ? I am facing similar issue and your  response or answer to this question will help. Thanks.